# How to optimize MySQL query ‘SELECT * from table WHERE Date=CURDATE() and ID=1;’

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in a MySQL table `table`:

`ID`: int(11)  [this is the primary key]

`Date`: date

and I run the MySQL query:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE Date=CURDATE() and ID=1;
```

This takes between 0.6 and 1.2 seconds.

Is there any way to optimize this query to get results quicker?

My objective is to find out if I already have a record for today for this `ID`.

Comment: Are you saying that ID is not unique? Do you have a primary key in your table? And to optimize any query you should indexes on any field that is used in the `WHERE` part of your query. (in this case `Date` & `ID`)

Comment: create index for each column.or primary for id.

Comment: @gnur Yes, `ID` is the primary key.

Comment: please show EXPLAIN for this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add indexes on `ID` and `Date`.

See [`CREATE INDEX` manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html).

Comment: Trying to add an Index for Date with the query: 'ALTER TABLE  table ADD UNIQUE  `DATEINDEX` (  `Date` )' , but I am getting an error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '2011-04-21' for key 'DATEINDEX'"

Comment: Drop the UNIQUE keyword. It shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `limit 1` at the end, since you are searching for a primary key the max results is 1.

And if you only want to know wether it exists or not you could replace `*` with `ID` to select only the ID.

Furthermore, if you haven't already, you really need to add indexes.

Comment: Thank you @gnur; already adding Limit 1 and SELECT 'ID' brings it down by 50%. I'll look into indexes as well.

Answer (score 1):

SET @cur_date = CURDATE()

...WHERE Date = @cur_date ...

and then create an index of Date, ID (order is important, it should match the order you query on).

In general, calling functions before you do the query and storing them to variables lets SQL treat them like numbers instead of functions, which tends to allow it to use a faster query algorithm.